# Efficient method to regex and subcategorize in preferred order

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to find an efficient approach to an issue.

I have a categorization structure that I'm building that looks like this:

```
Food           Drinks          Condiments          Other 

chocolate      wine            ketchup             anything else
beef           alcohol         mustard
meat           water           honey
avocado        liquor 
bread
```

Data I have looks like:

```
ID    FieldOne     FieldTwo       FieldThree    FieldFour
210   beefmeat     chocolate/twi  kaetfn        chocolate
1520  .winefk      avocadocho     NULL          imhungry
8889  kjhajgkjte   test.com       subtle        NULL       
1381  NULL         NULL           NULL          NULL
```

Say I'm searching through 4 different texts / 4 different reference fields (FieldOne:FieldFour), and this has 2 process categorization method. Identify subcategories, then identify categories.

The second step is simple, I'll just categorize Food, Drinks etc. based on the subcategory column created from the first step.

The first step is where I'm playing with ideas.

This is done on a bigger scale, and ideally I'd like to search through 4 reference fields in a specific order: to **first** match any Food subcategories (i.e chocolate, beef), next match any Drinks subcategories and so on (lastly, anything that isn't matched is Other).

I was thinking I could concat the 4 reference fields into one string, one column -> search through concated field with some regex and create multiple CASE WHEN statements to categorize, but I'm not sure how to apply the order I want on the categorization with the CASE WHEN, or if there might be a more efficient approach.

End result would look like (reference fields not necessary, but thought it would be nice to see how the results align):

```
ID    FieldOne     FieldTwo       FieldThree    FieldFour  Subcategory     Category
210   beefmeat     chocolate/twi  kaetfn        chocolate  chocolate       Food
1520  avocadocho   .winefk        NULL          imhungry   avocado         Food
8889  kjhajgkjte   test.com       subtle        NULL       Other           Other
1381  NULL         NULL           NULL          NULL       NULL            NULL
```

Comment: you should clarify how your categorization table looks like - you mention categorization structure  - but it is still not clear how it is stored

Comment: @Mikhail any specific questions? The new subcategory and category columns will be stored and added in the same table with the reference fields.

Comment: my very specific question is  - where and how category structure is stored - what is the schema of the table where this data is stored?

Comment: If you’re referring to the initial structure outlined, that’s more of a reference sheet. The data I have to parse through is the second visual table in the post, used to create the end result table based on the reference sheet. The data is stored in a table with multiple other fields, but those 4 references are all that matter. The new columns will be added into that original table.